# Can I obtain the Swagger documentation from pre existing Java code?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am absolutly new in **Swagger** and I have the following doubt:

I know that gnerally I have to create Swagger document before code my REST API and the use this document to create my API (I know that from the Swagger Editor I can also generate my API server automatically).

My problem is the following one:

I am working on a Java application (a Spring Boot application) that implements my REST API. I want to use Swagger to create my API documentation.

Exist a way to automatically do it? From my Java code to the Swagger **yaml** file? For example annoting my Java code in some way that could be parsed by some tool?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a tool which can easily generate the swagger documentation from the code you have already written.

This included into a Spring Appllication will create the documentation
https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

To my mind this is the right way to it. Don't create a documentation and have the code generated, rather generate the documentation. That's the way Javadoc is created as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to annotate nothing in particular.

Create a class similar to the following to access the API with *Swagger*:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{

  @Bean
  public Docket api(){

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(
        RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.yourcompany.restcode")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
  }
}
```

Then access the API documentation with something like:

```
localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/
```

Comment: But is this configuration for Spring MVC or for Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring Boot configuration.